# Ansible how to run task only on groups mentioned in playbook and skip other groups even though same host part of other group

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a role that is common for both mongo replicas and arbiters and hosts groups separately for each replica and arbiter because the role should support the arbiter on the same host & different host.

hosts:

```
[replicas]
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2

[arbiter]
127.0.0.2
```

the task inside role:

```
- name: Run only on replicas
  debug msg=" Only on replica"
  when: '"replicas" in group_names'

- name: Run only on the arbiter
  debug: msg="Only on the arbiter"
  when: '"arbiter" in group_names'
```

playbook:

```
- hosts: replicas
  roles:
    - role: "common"
    - role: "replica"

- hosts: arbiter
  roles:
    - role: "common"
    - role: "arbiter'
```

Expected output while running on ***replicas***:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": " Only on replica"
}
ok: [127.0.0.2] => {
    "msg": " Only on replica"
}

TASK [debug(arbiter)] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1]
skipping: [127.0.0.2]
```

But is not skipping on arbiter task as expected **as the same host is part of replicas group.** Below is the actual output.
Actual output:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": " Only on replica"
}
ok: [127.0.0.2] => {
    "msg": " Only on replica"
}

TASK [debug(arbiter)] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1]
ok: [127.0.0.2] => {
    "msg": " Only on replica"
}
```

How to run on a specific group that playbook delegated?

Answer (score 1):

hello you can use this method:
Playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: replicas
  roles:
    - { role: common, vars: { group: "replicas" } }
    - { role: replica, vars: { group: "replicas" } }

- hosts: arbiter
  roles:
    - { role: common, vars: { group: "arbiter" } }
    - { role: arbiter, vars: { group: "arbiter" } }
```

and inside your role:

```yaml
- name: Run only on replicas
  debug msg=" Only on replica"
  when: group == "replicas"

- name: Run only on the arbiter
  debug: msg="Only on the arbiter"
  when: group == "arbiter"
```

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: This will work and I have similar kinds of variables already, just looking is there any ansible default value like ```playbook_hosts```.